# Exclude a set of file types when running rsync

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I'm running the following rsync command

```
rsync --times -v --recursive --compress --exclude "*.svn" --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh source/folder/ user@ip:httpdocs/
```

which excludes *.svn files when running. My question is how do I pass it a list of file types to exclude. There are a lot of non-essential hidden files in our development copy (IDE project files and osx specific files)

I need to pass in a list of 5 or 6 file extensions for rsync to ignore.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the **--exclude-from** option, and specify a text file with all the patterns you want to avoid in it, like:

```
rsync --times -v --recursive --compress --exclude-from /tmp/filelist.txt --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh source/folder/ user@ip:httpdocs/
```

Comment: Or you can specify the --exclude option multiple times.

Comment: Great thanks, do I just put the file types each on a new line in /tmp/filelist.txt ?

Comment: I like it when my command lines span both my monitors :)

Comment: ...and yes, each pattern on a new line.

Comment: You can say `--exclude={"/tmp","/lost+found:} etc.  But NEVER use the backslash to shorten pieces of the list to fit your screen - it breaks it.  Instead, use multiple excludes, like @wombie said.  Or use the list in a file.  RainyRat has a real point there.  Not to mention having to scroll right and left if these long command lines get posted here.

Comment: Unfortunately, `rsync` with `--delete` does not remove files on the destination server that are in `--exclude` or `--exclude-from`. Any way to achieve that?